# Wrong cell is reloaded/reused after DidSelect method is called post-scroll in TableView [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift5

Alright, I'm 14 hours deep on this one and still cannot solve this.

The problem arises when a new object is added to the array AND the user has scrolled, the DidSelect method still works as expected, but once that method has completed the cellForRowAt method is called (don't understand why) and it reloads the wrong cell. Here's my cellForRowAt omitting inconsequential code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "doghouseCell", for: indexPath) as! DoghouseTableViewCell
    
    // Reset for dequeue
    cell.actTimeButton.isEnabled = false
    cell.addNoteLabel.isHidden = true
    cell.addNoteTextView.isHidden = true
    cell.cancelButton.isHidden = true
    cell.doneButton.isHidden = true
    cell.buttonStackView.isHidden = true
    cell.noteStackView.isHidden = true
    cell.editButton.isHidden = true
    cell.actTimeButton.borderColor = UIColor.clear
    
    // Hide skeleton if all data is received
    if allDataReceived == true || firstLoginToday == true {
        cell.hideAnimation()
    }
    
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        // Get routine for this row
        let routine = routines[indexPath.row]
        print("CellFor Routine is \(routine.actTitle) at IndexPath: \(indexPath.row). Complete? \(routine.comp)")
        let timeConverted = Utilities.convert24to12(inString: routine.time)
        
        if routine.Aid.contains("custom") {
            cell.editButton.isEnabled = true
            cell.editButton.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        } else {
            cell.editButton.isEnabled = false
            cell.editButton.backgroundColor = .systemGray4
        }
        
        if indexPath.row == longPressIndex {
            
            // Set the time, title & desc.
            //OMITTED
               
            return cell
            
        } else {
            
            // Set the time, title & desc.
            cell.actTitle?.text = routine.actTitle
            cell.actDescription?.text = routine.actDescription
            
            if routine.comp == true {
                for routine in self.routines {
                    print("CELLFOR \(routine.Aid) \(routine.actTitle) \(routine.comp)")
                }
                print("routine \(routine.actTitle) is complete at indexPath: \(indexPath.row)")
                tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
                cell.checkedImage.image = UIImage(named: "checkmark")
                cell.actTitle.textColor = #colorLiteral
                cell.actDescription.textColor = #colorLiteral
                // For hiding the title on the button when data is not yet received
                if allDataReceived == true || firstLoginToday == true {
                    cell.actTimeButton.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral)
                    cell.actTimeButton.setTitle(timeConverted, for: .normal)
                } else {
                    cell.actTimeButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
                }
            } else {
                tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
                cell.checkedImage.image = UIImage(named: "unchecked")
                cell.actTitle.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
                cell.actDescription.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
                // For hiding the title on the button when data is not yet received
                if allDataReceived == true || firstLoginToday == true {
                    cell.actTimeButton.setTitleColor(.darkGray, for: .normal)
                    cell.actTimeButton.setTitle("⏱\(timeConverted)", for: .normal)
                } else {
                    cell.actTimeButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
                }
            }
            
            return cell
        }
        
    } else {
    // Section 2 - Wrap Up
        
      return cell
    }
    
}
```

And here's my DidSelect Method which works as expected, again with omissions. I'm also using the deselect method, which works as expected on it's own and is basically the opposite of the didSelect:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! DoghouseTableViewCell

    selectedRow = indexPath.row
    haptic.notificationOccurred(.success)
    
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
    
        // Get routine for this row
        let routine = routines[indexPath.row]
        let timeConverted = Utilities.convert24to12(inString: routine.time)
        print("Selected Routine is \(routine.actTitle) at IndexPath: \(indexPath.row)")
        
        if routine.comp == false {
            routine.comp = true
            // EDIT REMOVED tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
            // EDIT REMOVED cell.checkedImage.image = UIImage(named: "checkmark")
            // EDIT REMOVED cell.actTitle.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.195538193, green: 0.7439816594, blue: 0.6510779262, alpha: 1)
            // EDIT REMOVED cell.actDescription.textColor = #colorLiteral
            // EDIT REMOVED cell.actTimeButton.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral)
            // EDIT REMOVED cell.actTimeButton.setTitle(timeConverted, for: .normal)
            print("Selected \(routine.actTitle) Routine is complete? \(routine.comp) at IndexPath: \(indexPath.row)")
            for routine in self.routines {
                print("DIDSELECT \(routine.Aid) \(routine.actTitle) \(routine.comp)")
            }
            
        } else {
            // routine.comp is false (shouldn't happen here)
        }
        print("DidSelect Complete")
        
    } else {
        // Section 2 - Wrap Up
    }
}
```

The array updates from the didSelect method as expected using a boolean in the objects of the array to setSelected. Here's a snapshot of the during user selection row 5 and then after when cellForRowAt runs (again, don't know why):

```
| DidSelect | CellForRowAt (after DidSelect) | 
| --------- | ------- | 
| Value0 routine.comp = False     | Value0 routine.comp = False   | 
| Value1 routine.comp = False     | Value1 routine.comp = False   | 
| Value2 routine.comp = False     | Value2 routine.comp = False   | 
| Value3 routine.comp = False     | Value3 routine.comp = False   | 
| Value4 routine.comp = False     | ***Value4 routine.comp = True*** X   | 
| Value5 routine.comp = True      | Value5 routine.comp = True    | 
| Value6 routine.comp = False     | Value6 routine.comp = False   | 
| Value7 routine.comp = False     | Value7 routine.comp = False   |
```

I thought the issue was a discrepancy in the array between the didSelect and cellForRow when a new value is added/removed, but they both contain the same objects.

**The problem is, when row 5 is tapped, didSelect updates the array and it's objects correctly (all is good!), but then cellForRowAt is called and it updates the wrong row (row 4).**

**If two new objects are added and row 5 is tapped, cellForRow will update row 3.**

This only happens after scrolling AND a new object has been added to the array. It works perfectly if a new object is added to the array and the user hasn't scrolled. And it works perfectly if no new objects are added to the array and the user scrolls.

Below is a snapshot of the UI. Green is the tapped cell, Red is the cell being reloaded:

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: Modifying the **cell** outside of `cellForRow` can cause unexpected behavior. A more reliable way is to modify the **model** and to reload the row (which calls `cellForRow`).

Comment: Thanks for your help. So I believe I had it setup this way originally. On didSelect I modified the model (routine.comp = true) and left all of the cell modifications to cellForRow, but it still reloaded the wrong row in this instance

Comment: Why are you calling `selectRow` in `didSelectRowAt`?

Comment: What index path are you getting in the call for `cellForRow`?

Comment: @Paulw11 Why are you calling selectRow in didSelectRowAt? Out of desperation, I've been trying various things. Obviously this was a bad one. I've taken that out and it still performs the same.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm getting the wrong index at cellForRow. If I select indexPath.row 5, it reloads indexPath.row 4

Comment: Ok, regardless of which index it passes, if your code did the right thing, row 4 wouldn't be shown with the green & check mark since it isn't selected. Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through your code ?

Comment: You are calling cellForRowAt yourself in did Select

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Had to do with a check function that I was running to see if another user updated the DB values that populate this table--I didn't realize it was running after didSelect. I've made the appropriate edits to the code above that the comments have mentioned and it works exactly as it should.